# SQL how to query on self-join

Tags: sql, join

A sql question confused me a lot, I have two tables like this

```
create table faculty
(fac No
 fac first name
 fac last name
 fac supervisor No)
```

another is

```
create table offering
(offer No
 course No
 offterm
 offyear
 offlocation
 offime
 facNo   )
```

now I need to write a query that list the names of faculty members and the course number for which the faculty member teaches the same course as his or her supervisor in 2010.

I try to write a query like this

```
select fa.FacNo,fa.FacFirstName,fa.FacLastName
from faculty as fa,faculty as fs,Offering as o, Offering as os
where fa.FacSupervisor = fs.FacNo
and fa.FacNo = o.FacNo
and fa.FacSupervisor = os.FacNo
and o.OffYear = 2010
```

but I cant have the right answer, so please give me some hints

Thanks for every one, I worked it out as below

```
select f.FacFirstName,F.FacLastName,s.FacFirstName as SupFirstname,s.FacFirstName as        SupLasName,o.CourseNo
from faculty as f, Faculty as s ,Offering as o, Offering as os
where f.FacSupervisor = os.FacNo
and f.FacNo = o.FacNo
and o.CourseNo = os.CourseNo
and f.FacSupervisor = s.FacNo
and o.OffYear =2010 and os.OffYear =2010
```

I hope this is helpful for some new SQL leaner who faces the same issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"so please give me some hints"

Since that is you're question, I am happy to provide a hints.

Make your joins explicit--it helps readability immensely. For example:

```
FROM faculty as fa
     INNER JOIN
     faculty as fs ON fa.FacSupervisor = fs.FacNo
     INNER JOIN
     Offering as o ON fa.FacNo = o.FacNo
     INNER JOIN
     Offering as os ON fs.FacNo = os.FacNo
```

Once you do that I suspect you'll have much better luck seeing any problems. Or at elast if will be easier for us to help more.

You then need to filter with

```
WHERE o.[course No] = os.[Course No]
  AND o.OffYear = 2010
```